# Create pretty permalink for a post knowing the permalink structure

Tags: posts, permalinks, feed

How can I generate a pretty permalink correctly for a post knowing the permalink structure?

My posts where processed with the FeedWordPress plugin with the "Link" setting set to "Permalinks point to: The copy on the original website".

So for all the posts in the admin area when editing a post the "Permalink" field under the post title shows an original, external site's URL, which is stored in the "syndication_permalink" meta data.

What I would like to do is to generate a pretty permalink for all such posts that would point to a local host (i.e. the post will have a permalink of type "http://mysite.com/" rather than have an external link to a source), so that I can update the permalinks in DB.

I can get the permalink structure using `get_option('permalink_structure')`. Is there a WP function that I can use to get a pretty permalink generated correctly for a post by its ID?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Dasha

Comment: P.S. Maybe there is an easier way to "revert" posts from FeedWordPress into "local" posts?

Comment: Updated the question, got confused with GUID and permalinks, as @Rarst mentioned they aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUID and permalink are two completely independent things. GUIDs are usually based on permalinks, but they don't have to be. Permalinks are not based on GUIDs in any way in modern WP (it had been changed long ago).

If you permalinks are not being generated correctly then that plugin (or some other) is breaking something in a bad way, it is unrelated to what your GUIDs contain.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. The plugin generated links correctly, making the permalink of posts to be original, external links. Now, however, I need to make them point to local posts, so that posts' permalinks will be of type "http://mysite.com/<permalink_structure>". I don't know how I can generate a pretty permalink for a post by its ID. I was hoping I can, so then I can update the permalink for that post in the DB from external to local.

Comment: @dashaluna are you talking about links to the posts or links in the post content? Also see [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) which is what you are asking literally here, but I am not sure if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The permalinks are not something that's "generated" per se... they're something that's parsed to point to a certain post.

If you imported posts using FeedWordPress, FeedWordPress doesn't do anything to actually change your permalink... it just creates a post meta field called 'syndication_permalink' that it then uses to filter functions like `get_permalink` etc. If you delete that meta field or remove the filter (ie disabling the plugin), then functions like `get_permalink` will point to the local post.

Alternately, FWP includes a function for getting the local permalink. Try calling `get_local_permalink( $post_ID )` for that.